# JDBC install and configuration with Java SE 6 and Tomcat 6 - help please

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am new to Tomcat and Java SE 6 and need to know what I need to do to install, configure and use the Microsoft JDBC driver.

I have download the JDBC driver and extracted it to a directory on a windows 2008 system. I am going to install a couple of Java applications into tomcat 6 that need to talk to a SQL database.

Do I need to copy files from the JDBC directory to the tomcat directories or the java application directories installed in tomcat?

Do I need to configure any anything anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the links that Gagandeep provided will say, in order for your JVM to make a database connection, the JDBC driver jar(s) have to be on the classpath, and you'll need to provide your Java program with an appropriate connection string and credentials.

As far as what you need to do specifically with Tomcat, that depends quite a bit on your applications and how they retrieve a connection to the datab

Now there are a few options as far creating and providing this connection. With Tomcat and Java EE applications, your Java application could define a  in its web.xml. Tomcat would be responsible for creating/maintaining the connection (pool) and providing it to the application as needed. In this case the driver would have to be on Tomcat's classpath, you'd need some configuration in your application's corresponding context.xml and possibly even the server.xml. [Here's some Tomcat docs on this method topic](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

Alternatively, your application could be responsible itself for setting up and tearing down the database connections, in which case the driver jars probably belong in the WAR / part of the WAR's classpath. Then all that is needed is a method for getting the required connection information into the application (environment entries, property files, any number of other methods)...

Comment: Hi, thansk for the feedback, should have mentioned we are using Microsoft SQl 2008 R2 for the DB. Does this change anything ??? Really apprecaite your feedback, Cheers, Jeff.

Comment: Hi Jeff- it might change what version of the driver you grab and use, but the process is the same for any JDBC connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Getting Started with JDBC Drivers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)

One more Link [Getting Started with Microsoft JDBC Drivers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100)

I had done some research now, regarding your asked question. What I found out is this.
Once you had downloaded your drivers, simply add them to the classpath of your Operating System. Now how to put them to your Tomcat part, I will suggest you do the MVC Model Approach, where the request will come to your servlet and then your class which will make the connection with your Database will be just one normal class, and your Servlet class will call this class which makes Connections with your Database and will send the needed fields back to the Servlet class.
I had tested the drivers with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and the following code works with that :

```
import java.*;
public class Connect
{
    private java.sql.Connection  con = null;
    private final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
    private final String serverName= "localhost";
    private final String portNumber = "1433";
    private final String databaseName= "yourDatabaseName";
    private final String userName = "yourUserName";
    private final String password = "yourPassword";
    // Informs the driver to use server a side-cursor, 
    // which permits more than one active statement 
    // on a connection.
    private final String selectMethod = "cursor"; 

    // Constructor
    public Connect(){}

    private String getConnectionUrl()
    {
        return   url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";
    }

    private java.sql.Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(),userName,password);
            if(con!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }

    /*
         Display the driver properties, database details 
    */ 

    public void displayDbProperties()
    {
        java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            con= this.getConnection();
            if(con!=null)
            {
                dm = con.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver Information");
                System.out.println("\tDriver Name: "+ dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("\tDriver Version: "+ dm.getDriverVersion ());
                System.out.println("\nDatabase Information ");
                System.out.println("\tDatabase Name: "+ dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("\tDatabase Version: "+ dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                System.out.println("Avalilable Catalogs ");
                rs = dm.getCatalogs();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                     System.out.println("\tcatalog: "+ rs.getString(1));
                } 
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
                closeConnection();
               }else System.out.println("Error: No active Connection");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dm=null;
    }     

    private void closeConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if(con!=null)
            con.close();
            con=null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Connect myDbTest = new Connect();
        myDbTest.displayDbProperties();
    }
}
```

This code has some slight changes then the one provided in the Link given by me. Do add the sqljdbc.jar to your classpath and provide your DatabaseName, UserName and Password and try to run this code. If it's a success, then use one MVC (Model View Controller) Pattern for your Web Application, in which the request comes to the servlet, servlet passes it to the normal Java class, making the connection to the database and accessing database, and then retrieve what you need back into the Servlet class.

Comment: The edit severely detracts from your original. 1) We don't know if he's writing the application or not 2) If he is, he should let the container (Tomcat) do it's job in setting up the connection and retrieving in the app via a resource-ref. (JPA & JTA might be useful techs too, but not directly applicable to the Q) 3) MVC is not applicable here, it's a question about database connections, not code structure 4) You should NOT just throw jars onto the OS classpath as this could cause side-effects to other JVMs on the same system. 5) If you post altered code, what changes did you make and why?

Comment: @Charlie : If you will go with MVC, I mean he doesn't need to provide any classpath on Tomcat, Simply he can run his application on Tomcat and the work related to retrieving info from Database can be done by a simple Java Class other than the Servlet. Changes made to my post are just related to url and things mentioned in my answer, password username etc. And with my answer I never side tracked from the question asked, it's just one information that you can connect this way too.

Comment: 1) I'm not arguing that MVC is indeed a solution to separating concerns, I'm arguing that it's irrelevant to this question. 2) He still needs to provide classpath entries to Tomcat else the driver wouldn't be present to be used. (You're doing this by altering the entire system, which is a really bad idea). 3) Such minor changes don't need to be reposted because any reasonable person following your link would be able to figure out such details. Doing so is unnecessary noise at best, and copyright infringement at worst.

Comment: @Charlie : i don't think so he needs to provide anything to the Tomcat, in any sense, my computer is the server. I had done that part without giving anything to the Tomcat. That was my point of referring to MVC, that you have to do nothing to the Tomcat. Moreover, there is nothing like copyright infringement in any case, God knows what you are up to :-)